# Updating Arraylist by reading from dat file

Tags: java, arraylist

so part of my program does is to create a card with a name. ill then check if the name exists in my dat file.

first, what i do is i read in my dat file and stores into an arraylist. then i implement a method to check if name exists. if not, then go ahead with creation.

but the thing is, after creation, i need to update my existing arraylist as my dat file has been updated with the newly added name.

what im thinking now is to clear my existing arraylist and then reading+store it again.

but i keep running into exceptions when i introduce the clear method. Here are my tested codes:

`private ArrayList<Cards> cardList;`

```
public void readGameCards()
{               
    cardList = new ArrayList<Cards>();
    //clearCards(this.cardList); -> not sure where to add this

    try // get data from dat file and store it into arraylist
    {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File("GameCards.dat"));

        while (myScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            //converting codes

            Cards c = new Cards(//para);

            cardList.add(c);
        }

        myScanner.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
    {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}

public void clearCards(ArrayList<Cards> cardList)
{
    if (!cardList.isEmpty())
    {
        cardList.clear();
        //cardList = new ArrayList<Cards>();
    }
}
```

it works fine for the first run, but on second run, the newly added name is not reflected in the arraylist.

Comment: What exception are you facing ?

Comment: if i place my clearCards() before the new arraylist, i get nullpointer.
if i place it after, i get indexoutofbounds.

Comment: Your condition to check if cardList is empty may give you nullpointer exception as cardlist can be empty. Why don't you use CollectionUtils.isEmpty() from apache commons. Also I don;t understand how you ended up getting indexoutofbounds. Can you explain it with code ?